# How to getElementBy...Value?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

Normally, when we want to click a radio button automatically on a website, we would use `getElementsByName()`, `getElementbyID()`, etc. However, if there is only value that can be use to identify the button, how this can be done?

```
<input type="radio" name="price" value="123" onclick="changeView(this);">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use document.querySelector().
It can take class names, id or even attributes. In your case, it will be

```
document.querySelector('input[value="123"]');
```